# rubyで指定した日のランダムな時刻を取得する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

rubyで日付だけ指定して、ランダムな時刻を設定したTimeオブジェクトを得る方法を教えて下さい。

例えば'2016/06/22'のランダムな日付が欲しい場合、
`2016/06/22 19:44:34`という感じです。

Answer (score 5):

その日付に一日の秒数(24*60*60)未満の乱数値を加算するのはどうでしょうか。

```
r = Random.new
day = Time.local(2016, 6, 22, 0, 0, 0) + r.rand(24*60*60)
=> 2016-06-22 13:54:03 +0900
```

Answer (score -3):

```
def rand_str
  num = (0...60).to_a.sample
  num < 10 ? "0#{num}" : num.to_s
end

puts "2016/06/22 #{rand_str}:#{rand_str}:#{rand_str}"
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！これは `Timeオブジェクトが得られず、文字列が標準出力に流れるだけになってしまう` `「2016/06/22 58:30:00」のように、23時以降の時刻になる場合がある` `「2016/06/22 23:60:60」のように、60分や60秒など存在しない分や秒が得られるがある` という3点の問題があるため、マイナス票が付いているようです。

Comment: このプログラムで仕様を満たしています。

Comment: snxpwyf氏の質問した内容としては `Timeオブジェクトを得る方法` ですので、満たしていません。